# Unable to compile rustacuda on Linux: 'linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1'

Tags: linux, rust

I'm trying to build the basic [rustacuda](https://github.com/bheisler/rustacuda) example using `cargo build`, but I am getting the error:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.114qu21cmyxgm5vs.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.130tmtat0zrjo2g1.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.15brzeh653yx84a6.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.17jbii9zijh37jjg.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.18yjk17cfr819y8w.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.1a0fah2mumbeaumw.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.1cimqn8d9gj5vok.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.1db5rh3i9dt4e3lz.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.1gb5shwuid6pzxod.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.1o5y5zwtfv93r6og.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.1xo68oma4zrk4eg4.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.1xzbdr8svhuclhy7.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.241ihdeu7wf4ipqt.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.2c51ho6oiwcqjvv1.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.2chr72f12t8fd9gf.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.2yfh41y5eihwhaa8.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.3a5a41ou0q54qbzq.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.3oeokeiewje0j557.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.3pz55wtb7i2gf86g.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.3vgxaa6gtfuqmmez.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.42liv0986ykss7ps.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.48yahxkfhp06pfgy.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.49pugvri298rimvb.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.4m32ecgz8eri0qre.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.4nzsvwud929q7bn.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.4q5cfvh88socnc12.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.4vkk6p37e0vjleo2.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.5dw7cr2qjxl8mqfg.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.8l6kkr142tyxd9t.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.jlt8brtgsf99ub7.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.onbelurnvv1gxad.rcgu.o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.yte3xk9q6l3o5n3.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/rust_test-3c102f2d126c37d0.46jz4cvystllzxz0.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/librustacuda-c1901c84639ee5ec.rlib" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/librustacuda_core-f54c47e82bdeb5e8.rlib" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/libcuda_sys-7fc293ad3a914650.rlib" "/home/jonathan/Projects/rust_test/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-1324f5a1f5de34d5.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-4a76ff35a356aedf.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-e11c7b3b3225afe2.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libbacktrace-13217ede3d276f16.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libbacktrace_sys-621a9ee22da6caa1.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-546c844e8071bbeb.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-be9569e4d599746f.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-47d8845cef2a3bc5.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-017511bce73a530c.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-be7979c57a08057b.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-d6459c4f0817c67c.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-580035dd98451925.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-aee5c24fff305dea.rlib" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-8a55a4098920125a.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/jonathan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-9fc4b5be2ba5cc19.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lcuda" "-lcudart" "-lcublas" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think it is linked with this part of the installation:

```
export CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\lib\x64"
```

I am using Linux and thus can't use this. My best guess at what the equivalent is on Linux is:

```
export CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/"
```

I have also tried:

```
export CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/"
```

And as it suggested:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.2/"
```

All of which seem to produce the same issue.

I really have no idea what the error even is, little alone how to rectify it.

[My minimal reproducible example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IMazy9X-bC8t5_E9W6ilZaKQ8z3YzO6f/view?usp=sharing). It requires you have CUDA installed. While you can run this on Windows, I don't think you could reproduce the same error.

Comment: Do you have a `libcudart.so` file in `/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/`?

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step-by-step guide to use CUDA in Rust (tested on Ubuntu 19.04)

### Install CUDA:

```sh
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
sudo cp cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.2/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
reboot
```

Verify that it was successful after a reboot with:

```sh
nvidia-smi
```

Verifying driver versions:

```sh
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

Output (may differ for you):

```sh
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.129  Mon Jul 22 21:10:21 PDT 2019
GCC version:  gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)
```

Version:

```sh
nvcc --version
```

Output (may differ for you):

```sh
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

---

Add to your startup file end (e.g. `/etc/bash.bashrc`):

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:}/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
export CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
# Verify:
code /etc/bash.bashrc
code /etc/environment
code ~/.profile
```

Run:

```sh
echo $PATH
# Output:
# ...:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# Output:
# /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib:/home/wasmup/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl

echo $CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH
# output:
# /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
```

Then create a new Rust project (e.g. `cuda101`) and add dependencies:

```
cargo new cuda101
cd cuda101
cargo search rustacuda >> Cargo.toml
```

So the `Cargo.toml` file `dependencies` looks like this:

```
[dependencies]
rustacuda = "0.1.1"           # CUDA Driver API Wrapper
rustacuda_core = "0.1.1"      # Minimal kernel-support crate for Rustacuda
rustacuda_derive = "0.1.1"    # Custom Derive Macro for RustaCUDA
```

Download the `resources/add.ptx` file from the RustaCUDA repository and place it in the resources directory for your application:

```sh
mkdir resources
cp ../RustaCUDA/resources/add.ptx resources/add.ptx
```

Run:

```sh
cargo run
# Or:
cargo run --release
```

Output:

```sh
Sum is 30
```

---

`main.rs` file:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rustacuda;

use rustacuda::memory::DeviceBox;
use rustacuda::prelude::*;
use std::error::Error;
use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Initialize the CUDA API
    rustacuda::init(CudaFlags::empty())?;

    // Get the first device
    let device = Device::get_device(0)?;

    // Create a context associated to this device
    let _context =
        Context::create_and_push(ContextFlags::MAP_HOST | ContextFlags::SCHED_AUTO, device)?;

    // Load the module containing the function we want to call
    let module_data = CString::new(include_str!("../resources/add.ptx"))?;
    let module = Module::load_from_string(&module_data)?;

    // Create a stream to submit work to
    let stream = Stream::new(StreamFlags::NON_BLOCKING, None)?;

    // Allocate space on the device and copy numbers to it.
    let mut x = DeviceBox::new(&10.0f32)?;
    let mut y = DeviceBox::new(&20.0f32)?;
    let mut result = DeviceBox::new(&0.0f32)?;

    // Launching kernels is unsafe since Rust can't enforce safety - think of kernel launches
    // as a foreign-function call. In this case, it is - this kernel is written in CUDA C.
    unsafe {
        // Launch the `sum` function with one block containing one thread on the given stream.
        launch!(module.sum<<<1, 1, 0, stream>>>(
            x.as_device_ptr(),
            y.as_device_ptr(),
            result.as_device_ptr(),
            1 // Length
        ))?;
    }

    // The kernel launch is asynchronous, so we wait for the kernel to finish executing
    stream.synchronize()?;

    // Copy the result back to the host
    let mut result_host = 0.0f32;
    result.copy_to(&mut result_host)?;

    println!("Sum is {}", result_host);

    Ok(())
}
```

---

In case of error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart`

Create a soft link in the current directory:

```sh
ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.2.89 cudart
```

Verify new soft link:

```sh
ls -l /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.2.89 cudart
```

Comment: So this works when using `--release` but not without, why is this? (thank you I really appreciate your help btw)

Comment: `cargo run` works too. Also update `let context =` to `let _context =` as you see in the new edit. Try it again with `cargo clean` then `cargo update`  and `cargo run`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of the error listing:

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
```

So, **ld** is unable to find a library it needs, and you need to tell it where it should look for it. Paths to libraries can be supplied to the linker using the -L parameter. For instance, in my Linux system, when I want to compile my C++ programs using Boost::Python v1.70, I use the following commands:

```
g++ <cpp_flags> <include_paths> -L/home/roger/boost-1.70.0/install-dir/lib -c <source_files> -lboost_python-py36
g++ <cpp_flags> -o <output_program> <object_files>
```

Comment: The linker here is being invoked by Cargo (Rust's package manager), not manually by the OP.